# What is the difference between delay() and delaymicroseconds()

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-nano

Does delaymicroseconds() provide something more than the time accuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more important difference between the two functions other than the unit of time the accept as parameters
the function delay() calculates time using the time interript of the arduino. However Delaymicroseconds() does not use the time interrupt
As you may know once an interrupt is called it stops all other interrupts
So the real difference is you can not use delay() in a program in which you are using an interrupt and instead, use delaymicroseconds() but be aware that it has a range where it is accurate and it is between 3 and 16383 micro seconds

Comment: That's not entirely true.  You can use delay in a program with an interrupt, you just can't use it in the ISR.

Comment: "delay() calculates time using the time interript" - that's not really of importance. As you can see in the source code ( https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring.c), `delay()` uses the `micros()` function which itself requires timer interrupts to increment a counter. The respective interrupt gets fired even if you don't use delays. As long as you don't need interrupts from the involved timer, there are no complications using interrupts and `delay()`. You are right about `delayMicroseconds()`: it counts a defined number of CPU cycles (determined by `F_CPU`).